# when I click on the button it appears TypeError: agregar_postulantes() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' Tkinter

Tags: python, database, tkinter

I hope you can help me with this problem

this is a function to save the data of a form in a database

```
def agregar_postulantes(self):
        con = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", user="root",password="", database="postulantebd")
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("insert into postulantes values(%, %, %, %, %, %, %, %, %, %, %)",(
            self.nombre_var.get(),
            self.apellido_var.get(),
            self.cedula_var.get(),
            self.fdn_var.get(),
            self.genero_var.get(),
            self.telefono_var.get(),
            self.correo_var.get(),
            self.estado_civil_var.get(),
            self.cargo_aspira_var.get(),
            self.txt_direccion.get(),
            self.descripcion_var.get('1.0', END)
            ))
```

and this is the button that executes it

```
add_btn=Button(btn_Frame, text="Guardar",width=10,command=agregar_postulantes)
add_btn.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=10,pady=5)
```

then I get the error TypeError: add_postulants () missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

i tried to change the button like this

```
add_btn=Button(btn_Frame, text="Guardar",width=10,command=self.agregar_postulantes)
add_btn.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=10,pady=5)
```

but I get this error

'postu' object has no attribute 'agregar_postulantes'

Answer (score 0):

The function `agregar_postulantes(self)` is apart of a class. when you are telling tkinter the function to call you must specify the class, this is because self represents the object made by the class witch the function would belong to.
try doing:

```
add_btn=Button(btn_Frame, text="Guardar",width=10,command=postu.agregar_postulantes)
add_btn.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=10,pady=5)
```

putting self instead would work if the button was made inside the class.

Let me know if this helps.
Thanks, Ronan.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering.
it didn't work. the function `agregar_postulantes(self)` is inside the postu class, not apart.

Comment: Have you tried changing it so that the line
add_btn=Button(btn_Frame, text="Guardar",width=10,command=agregar_postulantes)
is: 

add_btn=Button(btn_Frame, text="Guardar",width=10,command=postu.agregar_postulantes)

If this doesn't work ill run some tests on my own computer to try and find a solution for you.
Also, do you make the button inside the class, if so is it inside  __init__?

Comment: it didn't work using `add_btn=Button(btn_Frame, text="Guardar",width=10,command=postu.agregar_postulantes)` the button is inside the init, if you want I can send you the complete code to your email

Comment: Hi, I want to tell you that you already solve my problem. I decided not to use object-oriented programming